# Send a text in message body and not as an attachment

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, abap, sap-erp

I'm sending the email message from ***ABAP-report*** of *SAP ECC 6.0 EHP5* to *Microsoft Exchange* via *SMTP*. The message reaches user's inbox in *Outlook 2013*, but it arrives as an attachment instead to be in the body of the message. From the code's point of view, I'm sending the plain text, and I'm expecting to get it inside the message. Since I'm using the default ABAP-approach to sending emails, which sends text inside of an email body, I suppose that the root of the problem is in *Exchange/Outlook* side.

Is there any *Exchange/Outlook* setting, which explicitly directs to send the message as an attachment or inside of the message body?

Comment: Try sending a mail directly from the business workplace (SBWP). Does that mail arrive the way you expect it to?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I'm curious what you mean by "the default ABAP-approach."

Comment: Under «the default ABAP-approach» I mean the usage of standard SAP classes, not Z-development. The code fragment is published here: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3678931 I also tried implement the following example: http://scn.sap.com/message/15655684#15655684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples given, the body is always typed `HTM`. For the mail body I always use type `RAW` and this works just fine (with Lotus Notes). So maybe you try the following when creating your mail body:

```
document = cl_document_bcs=>create_document(  
                      i_type = 'RAW'  
                      i_text = im_text  
                      i_length = txt_len  
                      i_subject = im_subject ).
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But if I want to send HTML-page, which will be displayed in the message body (inline), what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook/Exchange doesn't provide anything for that. I suppose the issue comes from the ABAP/SAP software.